# Start Azure Storage Emulator for non-Admin users on Startup

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage-emulator

At work we use Azure functions for simple tasks.

To debug or run the function you need a running Azure Storage Emulator.

The problem is that our developer accounts don't have admin privileges so we can't start the emulator ourselves.
For now we solve this by asking an admin to start it for us, but that works only until you restart/turn off the machine.
We tried many things for the emulator to start for each user( as if it was run by the admin) but nothing worked.

Here is one of the methods we tried. A simple program that runs at startup and starts the emulator. If you start it manually as admin it does the job and the emulator starts without problems.
But when scheduled to start(with the admin account) at startup or at logon it starts it but only for the admin account and not the current user.

Code for the program we run at startup:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = "start";
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea or suggestions how to solve the above problem ?

P.S:I have searched the related topics posted on StackOverflow for issues of the same kind but they ware not much help or the use-case was different.

:)

Comment: Just want to clarify. 1. how did you add the admin privilege? ,  2. for "not for the current user", is that mean in the Task Manager, it runs under the admin account NOT the developer account?```

Comment: The admin set the task in the task scheduler and yes it runs only for him

Comment: one more thing, you just want to start the emulator at machine(machine or your program, please help clarify) startup and runs under the normal user, right?

Comment: Yes i want it to run for me

Answer (score 0):

As per this [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/af979b44-9a9c-4549-b3d0-4b96f03e650d/storage-emulator-initializing-requires-admin?forum=windowsazuredata): the first time you run your emulator, the emulator environment will need to configure itself: it will create a database in LocalDB and it will register some HTTP ports. In order for the configuration process to succeed, `you need administrator privilege`.

```
The next time you'll run the storage emulator, you will no longer need administrator privilege.
```

So there is a tricky way, just for your reference.

you can use administrator to start the emulator, then wait for a few seconds(it finishes the inialization), stop emulator.

Then you can use normal user account to start it, it would be run for you.

Code like below:

with admin account:

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = "start";
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();

        //Wait for finished initialization
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

        //After initialization, close the Emulator
        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("AzureStorageEmulator");

        foreach (var p in processes)
        {
            p.Kill();
        }

    }
```

Then you can start Emulator again using your developer account, the code is similar to the above.

It maybe a not good choice, you can also submit an question on [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues).

Comment: I tried this and the method proposed by ms, but the problem remains. Emulator still asks for admin. :(

Comment: Currently I don't have a clean environment, but I'll setup a clean env for this testing later.